# probability distribution of a random variable that is uniformly distributed in [-1, 1]

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

If $X$ is a random variable that is uniformly distributed between $-1$ and $1$, find the PDF of $\sqrt{\vert X\vert}$ and the PDF of $-\ln\vert X\vert$.
Solution or an explantion of approach wooulf work.

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Posts which state a problem to be solved but provide no context (where the problem was encountered, why it is difficult or important, or what approaches have already been tried) are usually closed.  If the problem is important to you and you have digested the problem statement before posting, it would ordinarily be easy to add a few words of context to your post.

Answer (score 3):

For $\sqrt{|X|}$, take a numbber $t\in [0,1]$,
$$
P(\sqrt{|X|} \leq t)=P({|X|} \leq t^2)= P(-t^2\leq{X} \leq t^2) =t^2.
$$
Differentiate and the density is $2t$ in $[0,1]$ and $0$ otherwise.

For $-\ln{|X|}$ take a number $t \in [0,\infty)$,
$$
P(-\ln{|X|}\leq t) = P(|X|\geq e^{-t}) = P(X\geq e^{-t} \text{  or  }X\leq -e^{-t}) =P(X\geq e^{-t} )+(X\leq -e^{-t}) \\=1-e^{-t}.
$$
Differentiate and the density is $e^{-t}$ on $[0,\infty)$ and $0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

$X \sim U[-1, 1]$, $Y = \sqrt{|X|} \Rightarrow$

$$
F_Y(y) = \text{Pr}\left(Y \leq y\right), \quad y \geq 0, 
$$

is a cumulative distribution function (c.d.f.) of $Y$ (by definition).

$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{Pr}\left(Y \leq y\right) &= \text{Pr}\left(\sqrt{|X|} \leq y\right) = \text{Pr}\left(|X| \leq y^2\right) = \text{Pr}\left(-y^2 \leq X \leq y^2\right) = \\
&= \left|\begin{aligned}
&\text{since }X\sim U[-1, 1] \Leftrightarrow \text{c.d.f. of } X\text{ is }\\
&F_X(x) = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
0, & x \leq -1 \\
\frac{x-(-1)}{1-(-1)} = \frac{x+1}{2}, & -1 < x \leq 1 \\
1, & x > 1 
\end{array}
\right.
\end{aligned}\right| = \\
&= F_X(y^2) - F_X(-y^2) = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
\frac{y^2+1}{2}-\frac{-y^2+1}{2} = y^2, & 0 \leq y^2 \leq 1 \Leftrightarrow 0 \leq y \leq 1\\
1, & y^2 > 1  \Leftrightarrow y > 1
\end{array}
\right.
\end{aligned}
$$

So, the c.d.f. of $Y$, $F_Y(y) = \text{Pr}(Y \leq y)$, $\quad y \geq 0$, is equal to

$$
F_Y(y) = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
y^2, & 0 \leq y \leq 1\\
1, & y > 1
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Then, the probability density function (p.d.f.) of $Y$ equals to

$$
f_Y(y) = F'_Y(y) = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
2y, & 0 \leq y \leq 1\\
0, & y > 1
\end{array}
\right.
$$